# Discord bot using python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i created a bot for discord using python but the problem it is when i stop PyCharm process then the bot  no longer works. I need some help thx.

This is a part of code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(id)

    if message.content.find("!about") != -1:
        await message.channel.send( "Hello, my name it is Py-Boot i am a beta version created by @Marin#2404, am not fully functionaly and Hello ")

    elif message.content == "!Users":
        await message.channel.send(f""" List of members: {id.member_count} """)

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Are you using windows, mac or linux?

Comment: Makes sense... You're stopping the bot, how is it supposed to work if it's not running? lol

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: If you stop the bot, theres no way for it to work. It has to be running, in order for it to work.

Comment: I know but i want to make like others bot from discord i dont think they have on process 24/24h

Comment: Use a hosting service like Heroku. You can learn how to set up a bot on Heroku [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U&t=401s).

Comment: @OneZero It sounds like you're a little new the concept of hosting an internet service yourself, which is what this is. You are going to need a computer that is always on 24/7, which can run a python process (and possibly have some sort of mechanism to detect if the process is not running properly and re-start it.) The 24/7 computer thing is why people are suggesting hosting, but something like a raspberry pi could work as well. Most servers run some sort of Linux which usually has `Cron`, but if you go windows, you could also use `TaskScheduler`

Answer (score 0):

If you stop Pycharm. Then the bot will stop running. Look into a crontab to run your bot temporarily, or some form of hosting if you'd like it to run forever and to be always available. Otherwise you'll need to keep the process running manually.

Comment: Cronjob it is for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. It's for all unix operating systems. It's a time based job scheduler. So you could do something like run your bot for a few minutes every hour etc.

Comment: I use windows so i cant use crontab

Comment: Have a look into hosting. https://www.writebots.com/discord-bot-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

You can technically make your bot run 24/7 for free by using UptimeRobot with repl.it, i'm also new to the discord.py scene but i've managed to make this happen

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok

thats the link for a quick tutorial, but heres the rough explanation

go to UptimeRobot and create an account, then add a new monitor with your discord.py's link (repl link), then the website will ping your code every 5 minutes which will make your bot not sleep

also create a new .py file called `keep_alive` next to ur discord.py file and copy this code in

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello. I am alive!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

then import the file name to the main discord.py file

```
from keep_alive import keep_alive
```

I am pretty sure you cannot do this in pycharm, cuz its not "pingable" by anything, so it'll shutdown when you shutdown ur computer. But its easy to trasnfer your code to repl.it since its just a copy paste.